# A reference for most used utility functions in macroeconomic problems of intertemporal optimization

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, dynamic-programming

I'm looking for a reference with the most used utility functions in macroeconomic problems of intertemporal optimization. The reference should preferably include a list of properties of those functions, and of why they are usually used.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I think that this article might be helpful:

“Exotic Preferences for Macroeconomists”

http://www.nber.org/chapters/c6672.pdf

They give a thorough explanation of many preference functionals and show their usefulness with macroeconomic applications.

Im not a specialist in macroeconomics, so I dont know the literature that well, but I think that the most used preferences nowadays are the Epstein-Zin preferences. The article I cite discusses thoroughly their properties.

A nice thing this paper has is that it contains detailed comments  from Peter Lars Hansen and Ivan Werning among others at the back.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Very Nice! Thanks. This one has a better version http://www.nber.org/papers/w10597.pdf

Comment: (+1 Forgot) I'll wait a bit more for others answer, before accepting one. ;)

Comment: Please note that the version you posted is a working paper version. The one I posted is the final one. I think (after a quick page-skipping) that the main text is the same, the only difference is that the figures are at the end and the comments from other economists are not present.